# Android - Bluetooth disconnects after starting different activity

Tags: android, android-activity, printing, bluetooth

Im doing a school project for android that uses a bluetooth printer. I bought a bluetooth device from someone and gave me a code snippets as shown below. I edited it for my preferences. The code, app and bluetooth printer is working. But my problem is that. The original code is design to print scan and print in 1 activity. I want to separate the scan bluetooth and print activity. In my scan activity, after selecting a device from the listview, i will be redirected back to main activity. And inside the main activity, I got disconnected from the bluetooth device. How can I maintain the connection of the bluetooth after selected in the entire app or to my selected activities inside the app.

```
public class BlueToothService {

private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
private Context context;
private int mState;
private int scanState = 1;
private Boolean D = true;
private String TAG = "BlueToothService";
private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
public static final int LOSE_CONNECT = 4;
public static final int FAILED_CONNECT = 5;
public static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 6;

public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int STATE_SCANING = 0;
public static final int STATE_SCAN_STOP = 1;

private static final int WRITE_READ = 2;
private static final int WRITE_WAIT = 3;
private static int writeState = 2;
private static int PrinterType = 0;
private static int PrinterTypeNow = 0;

private void SetWriteState(int state) {
    synchronized (this) {
        writeState = state;
    }
}

private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

private static final String NAME = "BTPrinter";

private Handler mHandler;

public BlueToothService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mHandler = handler;
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}

public boolean IsOpen() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (adapter.isEnabled()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public void OpenDevice() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public void CloseDevice() {
    adapter.disable();
}

public Set<BluetoothDevice> GetBondedDevice() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
    return devices;
}

public void ScanDevice() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    if (adapter.isDiscovering()) {
        adapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    SetScanState(BlueToothService.STATE_SCANING);
    adapter.startDiscovery();
}

public void StopScan() {
    context.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    adapter.cancelDiscovery();
    SetScanState(BlueToothService.STATE_SCAN_STOP);
}

public OnReceiveDataHandleEvent OnReceive = null;

public interface OnReceiveDataHandleEvent {
    public void OnReceive(BluetoothDevice device);
}

public void setOnReceive(OnReceiveDataHandleEvent onReceive) {
    OnReceive = onReceive;
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                SetScanState(BlueToothService.STATE_SCANING);
                OnReceive.OnReceive(device);
            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
                .equals(action)) {
            SetScanState(BlueToothService.STATE_SCAN_STOP);
            OnReceive.OnReceive(null);
        }
    }
};

public void ConnectToDevice(String address) {
    if (BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(address)) {
        BluetoothDevice device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        PrinterType = 0;
        PrinterTypeNow = 0;
        connect(device);
    }
}

public void write(byte[] out) {
    ConnectedThread r;
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
            return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    if (r != null) {
        r.write(out);
    } else {
        DisConnected();
        Nopointstart();

    }
}

public synchronized void start() {
    if (D)
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mAcceptThread == null) {
        mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mAcceptThread.start();
    }
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
}

private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    mState = state;
}

public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

private synchronized void SetScanState(int state) {
    scanState = state;
}

public synchronized int GetScanState() {
    return scanState;
}

public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {

    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

public synchronized void DisConnected() {

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mAcceptThread != null) {
        mAcceptThread.cancel();
        mAcceptThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mAcceptThread != null) {
        mAcceptThread.cancel();
        mAcceptThread = null;
    }

    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

private void connectionSuccess() {
    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    SetPrinterInf();
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, SUCCESS_CONNECT, -1)
            .sendToTarget();
}

private void SetPrinterInf() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            PrinterTypeNow = PrinterType;
        }
    }.start();
}

private void connectionFailed() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, FAILED_CONNECT, -1)
            .sendToTarget();
}

private void connectionLost() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, LOSE_CONNECT, -1)
            .sendToTarget();
}

private void Nopointstart() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, LOSE_CONNECT, 0)
            .sendToTarget();
}

private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket;
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                break;
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BlueToothService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        adapter.cancelDiscovery();
        SetScanState(STATE_SCAN_STOP);
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
            connectionSuccess();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG,
                        "unable to close() socket during connection failure",
                        e2);
            }
            BlueToothService.this.start();
            return;
        }

        synchronized (BlueToothService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

public void SetPrinterType(int type) {
    PrinterType = type;
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private boolean isCancle = false;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        isCancle = false;
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        int bytes;

        while (!isCancle) {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[30];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                if (bytes > 0) {
                    SetPrinterType(2);
                    byte[] by = new byte[bytes];
                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, by, 0, bytes);
                    if (buffer[0] != 17) {
                        SetWriteState(WRITE_WAIT);
                    } else
                        SetWriteState(WRITE_READ);

                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected1");
                    connectionLost();
                    isCancle = true;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected2", e);
                connectionLost();
                isCancle = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);
            Log.i("BTPWRITE", new String(buffer, "GBK"));
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            isCancle = true;
            mmSocket.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "562cancel suc");
            setState(STATE_LISTEN);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "565cancel failed");
        }
    }
}

public void PrintCharacters(String str) {
    byte[] send;
    try {
        String ss = str;
        send = ss.getBytes("GBK");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        send = str.getBytes();
    }
    write(send);
}
}
```

Selecting a button inside MainActivity will open this activity that opens the bluetooth device of the phone and scans a new bluetooth devices. After selecting my bluetooth printer device, I will be redirected back to MainActivity using intent. But the connected will be lost. Pls help me how to maintain the connection. THanks!

```
public class BTOptionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BlueToothService mBTService = null;
public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
private Button controlButton;
private ListView deviceList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = null;
private Set<BluetoothDevice> devices;
private Button bt_scan;
public Handler handler = null;
public Handler mhandler;
private LinearLayout layoutscan;
private TextView tv_status;
private Thread tv_update;
private boolean tvFlag = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_btoptions);

    deviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_device);

    layoutscan = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutscan);
    layoutscan.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mhandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BlueToothService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.STATE_LISTEN:
                        case BlueToothService.STATE_NONE:
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                            Toast.makeText(BTOptionsActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(BTOptionsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.FAILED_CONNECT:
                            Toast.makeText(BTOptionsActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.LOSE_CONNECT:
                            switch(msg.arg2){
                                case -1:
                                    Toast.makeText(BTOptionsActivity.this, "Lost Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                                case 0:
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    mBTService = new BlueToothService(this, mhandler);

    controlButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_openclose);
    if (mBTService.IsOpen()) {
        controlButton.setText("Disconnect");
    }
    controlButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mBTService.IsOpen()) {
                if (mBTService.getState() == mBTService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    mBTService.DisConnected();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mBTService.CloseDevice();
            } else {
                mBTService.OpenDevice();
                controlButton.setText("Connect");
            }
        }
    });

    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

    bt_scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_scan);
    bt_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mBTService.IsOpen()) {
                mBTService.OpenDevice();
                return;
            }
            if (mBTService.GetScanState() == mBTService.STATE_SCANING)
                return;
            layoutscan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();
            devices = mBTService.GetBondedDevice();
            if (devices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                            + device.getAddress());
                }
            }
            deviceList.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    mBTService.ScanDevice();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });

    mBTService.setOnReceive(new BlueToothService.OnReceiveDataHandleEvent() {
        @Override
        public void OnReceive(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if (device != null) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                        + device.getAddress());
            } else {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = 1;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    });

    deviceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (!mBTService.IsOpen()) {
                mBTService.OpenDevice();
                return;
            }
            if (mBTService.GetScanState() == mBTService.STATE_SCANING) {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = 2;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            if (mBTService.getState() == mBTService.STATE_CONNECTING) {
                return;
            }
            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
            mBTService.DisConnected();
            mBTService.ConnectToDevice(address);
        }
    });

    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mBTService.StopScan();
                    layoutscan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(BTOptionsActivity.this, "scan over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    layoutscan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    tv_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);

    tv_update = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (tvFlag) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                tv_status.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mBTService != null) {
                            if (mBTService.getState() == mBTService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                                tv_status.setText("Connected!");
                            } else if (mBTService.getState() == mBTService.STATE_CONNECTING) {
                                tv_status.setText("Connecting!");
                            } else {
                                tv_status.setText("Disconnected!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    tv_update.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    if (tv_update != null) {
        tvFlag = false;
        tv_update = null;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (mBTService != null) {
        mBTService.DisConnected();
        mBTService = null;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tvStatus;
private Button btnBTOptions;
private Thread tv_update;
private boolean tvFlag = true;
private BlueToothService mBTService = null;
public Handler mhandler;
public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
    btnBTOptions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBTOptions);

    mhandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BlueToothService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.STATE_LISTEN:
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.STATE_NONE:
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.FAILED_CONNECT:
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case BlueToothService.LOSE_CONNECT:
                            switch(msg.arg2){
                                case -1:
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lost Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                                case 0:
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    mBTService = new BlueToothService(this, mhandler);

    tv_update = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (tvFlag) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                tvStatus.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mBTService != null) {
                            if (mBTService.getState() == mBTService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                                tvStatus.setText("BlueTooth is Connected!");
                            } else if (mBTService.getState() == mBTService.STATE_CONNECTING) {
                                tvStatus.setText("BlueTooth is Connecting!");
                            } else {
                                tvStatus.setText("BlueTooth is Disconnected!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    tv_update.start();

    btnBTOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BTOptionsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: anyone pls help me lol